# Awesome floats some programs by default

Tags: kde, awesome

I have Kubuntu with KDE and replaced KWin with Awesome WM. It works well, except that it floats Konsole and Dolphin consistently.

While using KWin, I set up some KWin rules to fix the windows size, but I have deleted those rules in the KDE system settings by now, the issue persists.

How can I have Dolphin and Konsole tiled by default?

```
awesome v3.4.15 (Never Gonna Give You Up)
 • Build: Apr 28 2013 18:48:19 for x86_64 by gcc version 4.8.0 (buildd@batsu)
 • D-Bus support: ✔
```

My [rc.lua](https://github.com/martin-ueding/awesome-config/blob/master/rc.lua).

Comment: Can we see a copy of your `rc.lua` or distro default config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by unsetting the `maximized_vertical` and `maximized_horizontal` property like so:

```
-- {{{ Rules
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- All clients will match this rule.
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     focus = true,
                     keys = clientkeys,
                      maximized_vertical = false,
                      maximized_horizontal = false,
                     buttons = clientbuttons,
                 } },
```